# xlswriter on a EC2 instance

Tags: python, excel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, xlsxwriter

I am running my Python script in which I write excel files to put them into my EC2 instance. However, I have noticed that these excel files, although they are created, are only put into the server once the code stops.

I guess they are kept in cache but I would like them to be added to the server straight away. Is there a "commit()" to add to the code?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I guess they are kept in cache but I would like them to be added to the server straight away. Is there a "commit()" to add to the code?

No. It isn't possible to stream or write a partial xlsx file like a CSV or Html file since the file format is a collection of XML files in a Zip container and it can't be generated until the file is closed.